# How do I plot spatialpolygon dataframe layer on a leaflet map

Tags: raster, gdal, r, leaflet, spatial-statistics

I am not sure why this piece of code works

```
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
adm <- getData('GADM', country='SGP', level=1)
popup <- paste0("<strong>Name: </strong>", 
                adm$NAME_1)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=adm, weight = 2, fillColor = "yellow", popup=popup)


> head(adm)
       GID_0    NAME_0   GID_1     NAME_1 VARNAME_1 NL_NAME_1 TYPE_1 ENGTYPE_1 CC_1 HASC_1
260003   SGP Singapore SGP.1_1    Central      <NA>      <NA> Region    Region <NA>   <NA>
260001   SGP Singapore SGP.2_1       East      <NA>      <NA> Region    Region <NA>   <NA>
259999   SGP Singapore SGP.3_1      North      <NA>      <NA> Region    Region <NA>   <NA>
260000   SGP Singapore SGP.4_1 North-East      <NA>      <NA> Region    Region <NA>   <NA>
260002   SGP Singapore SGP.5_1       West      <NA>      <NA> Region    Region <NA>   <NA>
```

[image]

and why this doesn't works:

```
################################

library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

adm <- readOGR("MP14_SUBZONE_WEB_PL.shp")

popup <- paste0("<strong>Name: </strong>", 
                adm$SUBZONE_N)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=adm, weight = 2, fillColor = "yellow", popup=popup)
```

[image]

The difference between them is the shape file.

```
head(adm)
  OBJECTID SUBZONE_NO      SUBZONE_N SUBZONE_C CA_IND      PLN_AREA_N PLN_AREA_C       REGION_N REGION_C
0        1          1   MARINA SOUTH    MSSZ01      Y    MARINA SOUTH         MS CENTRAL REGION       CR
1        2          1   PEARL'S HILL    OTSZ01      Y          OUTRAM         OT CENTRAL REGION       CR
2        3          3      BOAT QUAY    SRSZ03      Y SINGAPORE RIVER         SR CENTRAL REGION       CR
3        4          8 HENDERSON HILL    BMSZ08      N     BUKIT MERAH         BM CENTRAL REGION       CR
4        5          3        REDHILL    BMSZ03      N     BUKIT MERAH         BM CENTRAL REGION       CR
5        6          7 ALEXANDRA HILL    BMSZ07      N     BUKIT MERAH         BM CENTRAL REGION       CR
           INC_CRC FMEL_UPD_D   X_ADDR   Y_ADDR SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area
0 5ED7EB253F99252E 2014/12/05 31595.84 29220.19   5267.381  1630379.3
1 8C7149B9EB32EEFC 2014/12/05 28679.06 29782.05   3506.107   559816.2
2 C35FEFF02B13E0E5 2014/12/05 29654.96 29974.66   1740.926   160807.5
3 3775D82C5DDBEFBD 2014/12/05 26782.83 29933.77   3313.625   595428.9
4 85D9ABEF0A40678F 2014/12/05 26201.96 30005.70   2825.594   387429.4
5 9D286521EF5E3B59 2014/12/05 25358.82 29991.38   4428.913  1030378.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data must be projected to WGS84 before plotting:

```
adm_proj <- spTransform(adm, ‘+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs’)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=adm_proj, weight = 2, fillColor = "yellow", popup=popup)
```